# Display 'Accept digital certificate' prompt using PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm developing a GIS: a web client to see some maps loaded from OGC servers.

The user can switch between use HTTPS connections and HTTP to load the maps, so I want to include some link to provide this funcionallity (because some maps can be loaded from an HTTPS url like this https://serverurl/ogc/... and others can be loaded from a classical HTTP url).

**When the user click on the link, it should display 'Digital Certificate' prompt on browser (to allow the user accept or deny the certificate).**

Is there any way to display this message to the user using Javascript or PHP?

Thanks in advance!

PS: the URLs are external, so creating an IFRAME like this doesn't work:

```
<IFRAME style="border: 0px;" SRC="https://externalurl/" width="100" height="100" >
```

With this error inside it:

> This frame has been blocked because it
>   contains some unsecure content

Only Chrome and IE show me that error. Firefox is able to load the prompt what I'm looking for, but only inside the frame.

I really appreciate if someone knows how to load this prompt at the entire webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there is no way to trigger this dialogue except pointing the browser to an actual resource where it would pop up anyway - loading such a resource in an invisible `iframe` should be enough to provoke it, for example. But you will definitely not be able to order the browser to show that specific dialog: It comes from the browser's security layer, and must by definition be outside the page's reach.

Comment: Thanks for your response Pekka, but I can't implement your solution because I want to load external HTTPS urls. So when I create an IFRAME with src="https://external...", it loads an error. What do you think that I should do?

Comment: @Fran I don't understand. Why would it give an error? An iframe's `src` can have any URL you want, it is not restricted by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I create the IFRAME inside of this (when I completely load the webpage), it shows me an error: "This IFRAME has been blocked because it includes non secure content". Sorry for the bad translation, but my browser language is spanish. I hope you understand the error message. Thanks again!

Comment: @Fran strange. In what browser is this?

Comment: Google Chrome. Firefox show me the prompt what I was looking for, but it's displayed inside the frame. Is it possible the display at the entire webpage view?

Comment: @Fran I don't know, it usually should display outside. Strange, didn't expect this to be so problematic! I don't know what to do in this case.

Comment: I hope someone can help me. Thanks again Pekka. I vote up your last comment :)